# SSIS ETL Design

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

SSIS ETL Design

I'm trying to build a ETL job. Below are  my primary design considerations

1. One master table to track data pull and status

Table Details

Table Name - JobStatus

- Columns - JobId, StartTime, EndTime, Status

Table Name - JobDetails

- Job_Detail_id, JobId, TableName, StartTime, EndTime, Status

Table Name - ErrorLog

- ErrorLogid, ErrorDesc, Time, Comments

How it Works

1. Whenever job fails, Job details table would help to figure out which is the last errored table, ETL job can start from that step
2. SSIS package would have DataFlow Tasks defined for each table between source and staging DB
3. Example of how it works

   - Put Entry in Job Status Table to start package execution
   - Each Dataflow task for individual table would put an entry in JobDetails table. After Loading data End Time and Status would be updated
   - On Error Status updated to Error and entry logged in Errorlog table

I would need your comments / feedback for this approach. Any bookmarks/blogposts for ETL design relevant to this example also would be helpful

Comment: Also posted this in MSDN forum, This approach seems fine - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlintegrationservices/thread/16df1485-18a3-4513-9771-de6bd92331d7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the requirements that you have mentioned about restarting the package execution from point of failure already exists in SSIS. You can use Checkpoint file to achieve that functionality. The in-built SSIS logging feature can help you to track the error messages and will help resolving the issue.

[**Click here**](http://learnbycoding.com/2011/07/ssis-etl-design-question-on-stack-overflow-and-msdn-forum/) to see an article that I have written on my website with respect to your question. I hope that might give you an idea about the functionality that already exist in SSIS and how you can make best use of it.

I think you can spend quality time on fine tuning your core business functionality than reinventing the process that already exists for the most part. The standard functionality might require some minor alterations based on our requirements but I don't think that you need to start from the ground up.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You are partially right, THis type of logging would help to restart from point of failure instead of starting from scratch. Thanks for your detailed post in your blog

Comment: Thanks Siva for taking time and providing step by step example. Now, I only need to store last run job time.